# update specific files in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that will work offline, and it's gonna be a big one, so I don't want the user to download 180 MB every time he connect to the internet (if there is an update).
so the thing is that I'm asking if there is a way to update a specific files in the extension.

Comment: Roll your own updating mechanism. Why is your extension 180MB, to start with? If you're using NaCl modules, take a look at [multi-platform zip files](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#multi-platform-zip) to reduce the size of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. The comment above is for native client apps, not chrome extensions. That comment is also wrong regarding using your own update mechanism, you cant either.